# Android VideoView plays audio and video out of sync

Tags: android, streaming, rtsp, android-videoview, rtsp-client

I have been using the Videoview to play a streaming RTSP video from a server. everything works fine expect for the video lag over the voice. Initially when the video starts the audio and video are in Sync (No mismatch atall)... but as time goes on the video seems to lag behind the audio. This lag keeps growing and I have noticed myself up till 30 sec and still keeps growing. This gives the user a very unpleasant experience.

I looking for a possible solution for this problem from the Android client as I have no control over the streaming server and also it has been verified to be fine on other platforms like desktop players, iPhone, BlackBerry etc. So my guess is there is problem with the video view in android only.

Here is the code I am usingt o intialize the videoview and load the URL to play

```
VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
   setContentView(mVideoView);
   mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp:................rtsp link "));
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
   mVideoView.start();
```

Any help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what device you're on and the codec you're using as well?

Comment: The codec is MPEG4 with 3gp wrapper